# Why is any variable used only inside the static method shared between threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, variables, methods, static

I have already read many articles about this problem from this page or other ones, but still cannot find the true answer. According to these answers, all the variables created inside the (static/instance) methods should be thread safe. Unfortunately this does not work properly.

I have this code:

```
public static void TestThreadSafetyOfInsideVariableOfStaticMethod()
{
    Thread t1 = new Thread(staticClass.Test) { Name = "t1" };
    Thread t2 = new Thread(staticClass.Test) { Name = "t2" };
    Thread t3 = new Thread(staticClass.Test) { Name = "t3" };
    Thread t4 = new Thread(staticClass.Test) { Name = "t4" };

    t1.Start();    t2.Start();    t3.Start();    t4.Start();
}


public static class staticClass
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream("C:\\test.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
            byte[] bytesToWrite = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " is currently writing its line " + i + ".\r\n");
            fs.Write(bytesToWrite, 0, bytesToWrite.Length);
            fs.Close();
            fs.Dispose();
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the TestThreadSafetyOfInsideVariableOfStaticMethod, then the output in the text file is this:

t2 is currently writing its line 1.
t3 is currently writing its line 1.
t4 is currently writing its line 1.
t1 is currently writing its line 2.
t2 is currently writing its line 2.
t4 is currently writing its line 2.
t2 is currently writing its line 3.
t1 is currently writing its line 3.
t4 is currently writing its line 3.
t4 is currently writing its line 4.
t4 is currently writing its line 5.
t1 is currently writing its line 6.
t1 is currently writing its line 7.
t1 is currently writing its line 8.
t2 is currently writing its line 9.
t1 is currently writing its line 9.
t3 is currently writing its line 9.
t4 is currently writing its line 10.
- end of the file.

I would expect that every thread will write its own line within its own for loop, so 40 lines, not sharing "i" variable in the for loop inside the method. Why they share this "i" variable???

Do I have to lock all the static methods within whole project? And what about parameters, the threads share it as well (I will not show the code, but I have already tested it).

Comment: The `i` won't be shared. Whatever is wrong here must have another cause.

Comment: Your code is not Java.

Comment: All 4 threads *are* writing e.g. `line 4`, however they do so at the same time, i.e. they all open the file for `Append` at the same time, which means they all position themselves at the same point in the file, then they all write to the file, with `t4` writing last, overwriting what the other 3 threads wrote. To prevent that, you need to control access to the shared resource.

Comment: @HenkHolterman the original question was tagged Java! Removing previous comment.

Comment: @driver - Your `i` isn't `static` at all, it's local. Local inside a static method but that doesn't really matter. Make the testclass non-static and get the same results.

Comment: But you're running in all the wrong directions. You should avoid `static` data and classes and avoid Threads (uses Tasks instead).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not that variable `i` is shared, but that the file `"C:\\test.txt"` is shared. You have four threads writing to it, all at the same time. There is absolutely no synchronization around these writes, so when several threads try to append their `"tX is currently writing its line Y"`, one is going to win, and the remaining ones will see their output dropped.

You can fix this problem by establishing a proper synchronization among the threads when accessing the file to prevent simultaneous appends.

Comment: There is an explicit Close+Dispose, per line.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Oops, I missed it, because they were all on the same line. Thanks for pointing it out, I edited the question to make Close+Dispose stand out.

Comment: OK, so you mean that all the threads check file size and start write at this address (at the end), so it can be rewritten by other threads?

Comment: @Driver Exactly, each thread finds the place at which to append, then commits the writings to the file system. If multiple threads go at the same time, they will write to the same spot, overwriting each others' work.

Comment: @Driver You can randomize the sleep to greatly reduce the problem. This way threads would go after the same spot a lot less frequently ([pastebin](http://pastebin.com/SYYwRhXY)).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight YES, you are right, I tried to write to other files ("C:\\test" + Thread.CurrentThread.Name + ".txt") and all the threads wrote all the ten lines. Thank you very much! :-)

Comment: Now I see that my question is voted negative with four votes. Is that normal in this site that if I cannot solve my problem, then there are immediately some idiots who vote me that this question is that bad?

Comment: @Driver Unfortunately, the site suffers a lot from lemming effect, when a couple of downvotes starts a stream of unwelcome "copycat" downvotes. There are questions that deserve such harsh treatment (mostly, these are homework dumps with no slightest attempt of independent work), but this question is definitely not one of them. The best strategy is to ignore such votes, because ultimately they are meaningless.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight : Thank you for your answer, I very appreciate your help, I was only interested in this behaviour. Thank you.